# ROS2: Override param value when running the node

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Guys,

ROS Version used : Dashing

I have a ROS2 package with below parameters set in `params.yaml` file.

```
node_name:  
  ros__parameters:
    node_topic : /some/topic
    scenario_id : scenario_1
```

I run my node `ros2 run package_name executable_name __params:=params.yaml` so that it takes the parameters value set in `params.yaml` file.

Now I would like to change value only for `scenario_id` while running the ros node in command line. Something like this `ros2 run package_name executable_name _scenario_id:=check_scenario`.

I have looked into the [ros2 tutorials](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Node-arguments/#setting-parameters-directly-in-the-command-line).
As per the tutorials given, looks like setting the parameters value in command line is not supported in Dashing.

Could anybody please suggest me if there is a way to do it?

Thank you,
KK

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/362910/ros2:-override-param-value-when-running-the-node/) by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on ROS Answers with karma: 262 on 2020-10-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are correct that setting individual parameters from the command-line is not supported in Dashing.

However, I think you can achieve what you want by passing multiple parameters files. For example, create a second parameters file, `params2.yaml` with the following contents:

```
node_name:  
  ros__parameters:
    scenario_id : check_scenario
```

and then pass *after* the first parameters file on the command-line:

```
ros2 run package_name executable_name __params:=params.yaml __params:=params2.yaml
```

The general rule is parameters in files passed later will override parameters from earlier files.

---

Originally posted by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) with karma: 1870 on 2020-10-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) on 2020-10-20**:
Reading your question again, I'm not sure if this is the answer you were looking for. Basically, you cannot set individual parameters directly from the command-line Dashing.

**Comment by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on 2020-10-21**:
Thanks for your answer. That was helpful.
However, I would really like if changing individual parameter values will be supported in future for Dashing as well. I have number of scenarios (20+), only that one value needs to be changed based on the requirement. Creating a params file for each scenario can be done, but may not be the ideal way to do.

**Comment by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) on 2020-10-21**:
It is very unlikely that this feature will be added to Dashing. We avoid backporting large changes to older ROS distributions so that we can maintain stability within a release. For example, backporting this feature would likely require that existing users of Dashing change their syntax for remapping from the command-line.

If you would really like this feature, I recommend upgrading to a newer ROS distribution.

**Comment by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on 2020-10-21**:
Yea.. Thanks for the update. Rest of the software stack is running with dashing. Until and unless the entire stack gets updated I cant update only this. :-(

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's now possible to do that with, at least, the ROS2 Foxy version.

`--ros-args -p scenario_id:="check_scenario"`

I also think the format for specifying multiple parameters via YAML has also changed.

Instead of `__params:=params.yaml` you know need to do `--ros-args --params-file params.yaml`

See the "Summary" section of this document: https://design.ros2.org/articles/ros_command_line_arguments.html

---

Originally posted by [bergercookie](https://answers.ros.org/users/25299/bergercookie/) with karma: 257 on 2021-11-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2